check if a spreadsheet column is linked to the form
I have a form with drop-down questions, the options are filled from a spreadsheet (to let the user manage),
the sheet look like this:
-----------------------------------
| option  | sub option            |
-----------------------------------
| opt1    |                       | 
-----------------------------------
| opt2    | sub2-1,sub2-2         |
-----------------------------------
| opt3    |                       | 
-----------------------------------
| opt4    | sub4-1,sub4-2,sub4-3  |
-----------------------------------


where the user is free to add options and to set sub options, the options with sub option have a "go to" actione to the related question.
To update the form my script have to delete all the questions related to sub option, delete all the option in the question and refill it again.
It work's fine, but recreating sub-question duplicate spreadsheet column.
I'm writing a function to move non-empty cell data to new columns and delete the old one, i can't find a way to check if a column is linked to the form.
the only way seem to try-catch to delete it, but in this way the unlinked column will be deleted and i loose the information i need.
So, is there a way to check if a column is linked to the form associated to the spreadsheet?

You could list the questions from the form and compare the values to the form headers. OR (and I think this might be a better option), unlink the form to the sheet, then create a new link to the same sheet. This will create a new sheet (such as "Form Responses 2") so that, depending on your preferences, you can aggregate ALL the form responses when and if you desire, or just look at the current linked sheet (getFormUrl).

You want to identify whether a column in a Form Response sheet is "linked" to an active question.
In this answer, I created a form with dropdowns and sub-dropdowns; then deleted the dropdowns and sub-dropdowns and created new dropdowns and sub-dropdowns.
The script consists of several elements:

get the Header Row from the "Form Response" sheet
get the linked Form
create an array of question titles

get the Items and Types
for types = "TEXT", "DATE", "TIME" and "LIST" (you may have others, expand the types as required)
get the item Title
push onto a temporary array


using IndexOf, test each Header value for a match in the item Titles

when the header is not an active question, push onto a temporary array
OR
when the header is not an active question, push the title and column number onto a temporary object




SCRIPT OUTPUT
Headers: [[Timestamp, Name, Date, Time, Name 2, Name 3, Sports, Rugby, Colours, Green]]
Item List: [Item, Item, Item, Item, Item, Item, Item, Item, Item]
Type List: [TEXT, DATE, TIME, PAGE_BREAK, TEXT, LIST, PAGE_BREAK, LIST, PAGE_BREAK]
Question Titles: [Name 3, Date, Time, Name 2, Colours, Green]
Unlinked Columns-Array: [Name, Sports, Rugby]
Unlinked Columns-Object: {2=Name, 8=Rugby, 7=Sports}

 /* 
*  Identify the columns on the Form Responses Sheet
*  that are NOT active questions.
*/

function getFormDetails() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = "Form Responses 1"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)

  // get column headings
  var lc = sheet.getLastColumn()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: last column = "+lc)
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,lc).getValues()
  Logger.log(headers) // DEBUG
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: number of columns in headers = "+headers[0].length)

  // get form url
  var formURL = sheet.getFormUrl()
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the form url is "+formURL)

  // open the form by URL.
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);

  // get items
  // Gets the list of items in the form.
  var items = form.getItems();
  Logger.log(items) // DEBUG
  //Logger.log(items.length) // DEBUG

  // Gets the type for each item and logs them to the console.
  var types = items.map((item) => item.getType().name());
  Logger.log(types);
  //Logger.log(types.length) // DEBUG

  // create a temporary array to hold Form Question Titles
  var qnTitles = []
  // get the titles
  for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    // test for "TEXT"
    if (types[i] == "TEXT"){
      qnTitles.push(items[i].asTextItem().getTitle())
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", type:"+types[i]+", title = "+items[i].asTextItem().getTitle()+", index:"+items[i].asTextItem().getIndex()+", ID:"+items[i].asTextItem().getId())
    }
    // test for "DATE"
    if (types[i] == "DATE"){
      qnTitles.push(items[i].asDateItem().getTitle())
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", type:"+types[i]+", title = "+items[i].asDateItem().getTitle()+", index:"+items[i].asDateItem().getIndex()+", ID:"+items[i].asDateItem().getId())
    }
    // test for "TIME"
    if (types[i] == "TIME"){
      qnTitles.push(items[i].asTimeItem().getTitle())
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", type:"+types[i]+", title = "+items[i].asTimeItem().getTitle()+", index:"+items[i].asTimeItem().getIndex()+", ID:"+items[i].asTimeItem().getId())
    }
    // test for "LIST"
    if (types[i] == "LIST"){
      qnTitles.push(items[i].asListItem().getTitle())
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", type:"+types[i]+", title = "+items[i].asListItem().getTitle()+", index:"+items[i].asListItem().getIndex()+", ID:"+items[i].asListItem().getId())
    }       
  }
  Logger.log(qnTitles) // DEBUG - list of question titles

  // find columns on the Response sheet that aren't in the form
  // create a temporary array yo hold the column names
  var unlinkedColumns = []
  // OR create a temporary object to track the column number AND the column name
  var columns = {};
  for (var c=1;c<headers[0].length;c++){
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: c="+c+", header value = "+headers[0][c]+", index = "+qnTitles.indexOf(headers[0][c]))
    if (qnTitles.indexOf(headers[0][c]) == -1){
      unlinkedColumns.push(headers[0][c])
      columns[(+c+1)] = headers[0][c]
    }
  }

  Logger.log("array")
  Logger.log("DEBUG: UNLINKED Columns - array")
  Logger.log(unlinkedColumns) // DEBUG: the array list
  Logger.log("DEBUG: UNLINKED Columns - object")
  Logger.log(columns) // DEBUG: the raw OBJECT list

}


This could be a way, but sometimes the new questions may have the same title of the old one.  The try-catch method  seem more efficient

sometimes the new questions may have the same title of the old one That's a fairly major issue - it would be worth including that in the question.

Have a look at my other answer. I used the Sheet to submit answers to all the active questions (as reported by the Form); the submission values include some clearly identifiable "dummy" values and the Form Responses sheet is updated. The blank columns are not linked to the Form. The Form has a feature where the "dummy" response can be easily deleted; and the submission can also be deleted from the Sheet.

You want to identify whether a column in a Form Response sheet is "linked" to an active question.
In this answer, the script creates a Form response containing identifiable "dummy" values. Every active questions are answered, and the Form Responses Sheet is updated (as for any submission). The blank columns on the submission row are "unlinked columns" relating to old/deleted questions. These columns can be deleted.
The submission can be manually deleted from the Form.

Open the Google Form, click "Responses":"Individual"

Go to the last response and confirm that the details are consistent with the values submitted by the function
Click the trashcan icon to delete the response.



Once the response is deleted from the Form, the submission row can be deleted from the Form Responses Sheet.

HT: @DanielH. Is it possible to create Google Form responses with data from Google Sheets?
/*  For a Sheet linked to a Google Form
*   find columns that are not linked to an active question
*   
*   IMPORTANT: Note the default values arounbd line 30
*   Enter this script in the linked spreadsheet and run the script
*   Review the Form Responses sheet - only active questions will have values (including the default values)
*   Review the Form Responses sheet - cells with no content are "old/deleted" questions
*
*   Open the Google Form, click "Responses":"Individual". 
*   Go to the last reposnse and confirm that the details are consistent with the values submitted by the function
*   Click the trachcan icon to delete this response.
*   
*   delete the submission row from the Form Responses Sheet
*/

function findUnlinkedColumns() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  var sheetName = "Form Responses 1"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  var submitSheetName = "submit"
  var submitSheet = ss.getSheetByName(submitSheetName)

  // get headers from linked sheet ignoring Timestamp
  var lc = sheet.getLastColumn()-1
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: number of columns= "+lc)
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1,2,1,lc).getValues()
  // Logger.log(headers) // DEBUG
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: number of columns in headers = "+headers[0].length)

  var numRows = 1

  // default values for active questions
  var textValue = "zzz"
  var d = new Date(2001, 00, 01); // 01 Jan 2000
  var timeHours = 13
  var timeMinutes = 52

  // get form url
  var formURL = sheet.getFormUrl()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the form url is "+formURL)

  // open the form by URL.
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);

  var items = form.getItems();
  // Logger.log(items) // DEBUG
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    var formResponse = form.createResponse();
    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
      // Logger.log("i: "+i+", j: "+j+", Type: "+items[j].getType()) // DEBUG
      var item;
      switch (items[j].getType()) {
        case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
          item = items[j].asListItem();
          var listChoices = item.getChoices()
          var listValue = listChoices[0].getValue()
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: LIST: ITEM: "+item.getTitle()+", choice#1: "+listValue)
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: LIST: Item number " + j + " is titled: " + item.getTitle()+", new value = "+ listValue );
          formResponse.withItemResponse(item.createResponse(listValue));
          break; 
        case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
          item = items[j].asMultipleChoiceItem();
          var mcChoices = item.getChoices()
          var mcValue = mcChoices[0].getValue()
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: MC: Item number " + j + " is titled: " + item.getTitle()+", new value = "+ mcValue );
          formResponse.withItemResponse(item.createResponse(mcValue));
          break; 
        case FormApp.ItemType.PARAGRAPH_TEXT:
          item = items[j].asParagraphTextItem();
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: Paragraph: Item number " + j + " is titled: " + item.getTitle()+", new value = "+ textValue );
          formResponse.withItemResponse(item.createResponse(textValue));
          break; 
        case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT:
          item = items[j].asTextItem();
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: TEXT: Item number " + j + " is titled: " + item.getTitle()+", new value = "+ textValue);
          formResponse.withItemResponse(item.createResponse(textValue));
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
          item = items[j].asCheckboxItem();
          var cbChoices = item.getChoices()
          // Logger.log(cbChoices) // DEBUG
          var cbValue = [cbChoices[0].getValue()]
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: CBOX: Item number " + j + " is titled: " + item.getTitle()+", new value = "+ cbValue );
          formResponse.withItemResponse(item.createResponse(cbValue));
          break;             
        case FormApp.ItemType.DATE:
          item = items[j].asDateItem()
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: DATE: Item number " + j + " is titled: " + item.getTitle()+", new value = "+ d );
          formResponse.withItemResponse(item.createResponse(d));
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.TIME:
          item = items[j].asTimeItem()
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: TIME: Item number " + j + " is titled: " + item.getTitle()+", new value = "+ (+timeHours+":"+timeMinutes) );
          formResponse.withItemResponse(item.createResponse(timeHours,timeMinutes))
          break;                  
        default:
          Logger.log("#" + (i + 1) + ":Do nothing for item " + j + " of type " + items[j].getType());
          continue;
      } 
    }
    formResponse.submit();
    Logger.log("end")
  }
}


